# when i add this select box in this select the button won't add ni field

Tags: javascript, php

```
$('#add').click(function(){ i++; $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td> <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
```

that one is working 
when i put this code it wont work

```
<td>
    <label for="Category">Category</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="product-categorie[]">
        <option value="">Select Product Category</option>
        <?php  
            foreach ($all_categories as $cat): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo (int)$cat['id'] ?>"><?php echo $cat['name'] ?></option>
        <?php 
            endforeach; ?>
    </select> 
</td>
```

the button won't add another field.

Comment: Could you pleas provide more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should help you get going. Based on your info and missing full HTML code, i just put basic selectors.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var i = 0;

  $('select').change(function() {

    i++;
    
    $('table tr:last').after('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td> <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="Category">Category</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="product-categorie[]">
        <option>Select Product Category</option>
        <option value="1">Some Name 1</option>
        <option value="2">Some Name 2</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```